# Heroku scheduler calls job but it doesn't get executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I am hosting my app with Heroku, and have a task in the `scheduler.rake` file (to be called by Heroku Scheduler):

```
task :send_recipe_summary => :environment do
  puts "Calling send recipe summary slack message job..."
  SendRecipeSummarySlackMessageJob.perform_later
  puts "Done!"
end
```

When this task gets called (by the scheduler or in the console) it says that the task gets enqueued:

```
➜  Plant-as-Usual-2 git:(master) heroku run bundle exec rake send_recipe_summary
Running bundle exec rake send_recipe_summary on ⬢ plant-as-usual-2... up, run.5548 (Hobby)
Calling send recipe summary slack message job...
I, [2020-09-24T16:25:50.193685 #4]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] Enqueued SendRecipeSummarySlackMessageJob (Job ID: a4110651-a9fa-4030-96ef-db4caf64c7e5) to Async(default)
Done!
```

However, in the logs, the job does not get enqueued, and the Slack message never gets sent:

```
2020-09-24T16:25:35.913315+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake send_recipe_summary` by user jonappleseed@email.com
2020-09-24T16:25:44.008993+00:00 heroku[run.5548]: Awaiting client
2020-09-24T16:25:44.039520+00:00 heroku[run.5548]: State changed from starting to up
2020-09-24T16:25:44.291580+00:00 heroku[run.5548]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake send_recipe_summary`
2020-09-24T16:25:49.334067+00:00 app[worker.1]: D, [2020-09-24T16:25:49.333949 #4] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mDelayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.5ms)[0m  [1m[37mUPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2020-09-24 16:25:49.331558', locked_by = 'host:9b1fc7b1-4107-427f-8f49-f058b41b7906 pid:4' WHERE id IN (SELECT "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2020-09-24 16:25:49.330595' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2020-09-24 12:25:49.330627') OR locked_by = 'host:9b1fc7b1-4107-427f-8f49-f058b41b7906 pid:4') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *[0m
2020-09-24T16:25:53.372387+00:00 heroku[run.5548]: Process exited with status 0
2020-09-24T16:25:53.407641+00:00 heroku[run.5548]: State changed from up to complete
2020-09-24T16:26:49.394474+00:00 app[worker.1]: D, [2020-09-24T16:26:49.394376 #4] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mDelayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.5ms)[0m  [1m[37mUPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2020-09-24 16:26:49.392377', locked_by = 'host:9b1fc7b1-4107-427f-8f49-f058b41b7906 pid:4' WHERE id IN (SELECT "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2020-09-24 16:26:49.391803' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2020-09-24 12:26:49.391827') OR locked_by = 'host:9b1fc7b1-4107-427f-8f49-f058b41b7906 pid:4') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *[0m
```

However, if I run the job itself (rather than the task), everything works as expected, and the message does get sent:

```
irb(main):002:0> SendRecipeSummarySlackMessageJob.perform_later
I, [2020-09-24T16:22:45.268729 #4]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] Enqueued SendRecipeSummarySlackMessageJob (Job ID: 8285bb7f-9646-42bb-9901-8d219ca1175c) to Async(default)
=> #<SendRecipeSummarySlackMessageJob:0x000055b1a768dfb8 @arguments=[], @job_id="8285bb7f-9646-42bb-9901-8d219ca1175c", @queue_name="default", @priority=nil, @executions=0, @exception_executions={}, @provider_job_id="c41cedd7-e5a5-4a7d-9e64-280d2ec81e1e">
irb(main):003:0> I, [2020-09-24T16:22:45.269348 #4]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [SendRecipeSummarySlackMessageJob] [8285bb7f-9646-42bb-9901-8d219ca1175c] Performing SendRecipeSummarySlackMessageJob (Job ID: 8285bb7f-9646-42bb-9901-8d219ca1175c) from Async(default) enqueued at 2020-09-24T16:22:45Z
D, [2020-09-24T16:22:46.412105 #4] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [SendRecipeSummarySlackMessageJob] [8285bb7f-9646-42bb-9901-8d219ca1175c]    (1.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."state" = $1  [["state", "awaiting_approval"]]
D, [2020-09-24T16:22:46.413683 #4] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [SendRecipeSummarySlackMessageJob] [8285bb7f-9646-42bb-9901-8d219ca1175c]    (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."state" = $1  [["state", "incomplete"]]
I, [2020-09-24T16:22:46.415123 #4]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [SendRecipeSummarySlackMessageJob] [8285bb7f-9646-42bb-9901-8d219ca1175c] Enqueued SendSlackMessageJob (Job ID: c640b706-9920-4639-a1a0-4c7dbec15c39) to Async(default) with arguments: "There are no recipes awaiting approval, and 1 incomplete recipe https://www.plantasusual.com/admin", {:nature=>"inform"}
I, [2020-09-24T16:22:46.415260 #4]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [SendRecipeSummarySlackMessageJob] [8285bb7f-9646-42bb-9901-8d219ca1175c] Performed SendRecipeSummarySlackMessageJob (Job ID: 8285bb7f-9646-42bb-9901-8d219ca1175c) from Async(default) in 1145.43ms
I, [2020-09-24T16:22:46.415882 #4]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [SendSlackMessageJob] [c640b706-9920-4639-a1a0-4c7dbec15c39] Performing SendSlackMessageJob (Job ID: c640b706-9920-4639-a1a0-4c7dbec15c39) from Async(default) enqueued at 2020-09-24T16:22:46Z with arguments: "There are no recipes awaiting approval, and 1 incomplete recipe https://www.plantasusual.com/admin", {:nature=>"inform"}
I, [2020-09-24T16:22:46.591446 #4]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [SendSlackMessageJob] [c640b706-9920-4639-a1a0-4c7dbec15c39] Performed SendSlackMessageJob (Job ID: c640b706-9920-4639-a1a0-4c7dbec15c39) from Async(default) in 175.12ms
```

Can anyone help me understand why the job runs as expected when run from the console, but it doesn't work when run from the scheduler?

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not enabled worker on heroku `bundle exec rake jobs:work`.
It is a paid service. goto: your_app > resource tab and enable it from there. [this link could be helpful](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job)

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't do anything. What do you think it going wrong? I already have a worker dyno running continually in the background. You can see in the third block of code the `2020-09-24T16:26:49.394474+00:00 app[worker.1]` lines. When I queue a job with `perform_later`, this is the worker than executes them.

Comment: did you migrate delayed_job migrations ?. It could be the jobs are not getting save to satabase

Comment: Yeah, I've done that. The jobs are working when called normally, just not when called with the Heroku task.